# Defining functions in javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I had [this](http://jsfiddle.net/TAnzA/5/), and it was working and all was good.
I then tried to make the change to [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Hxnv5/4/), and it all went wrong.
Am I defining functions in the wrong way? Sorry, I'm new to JS & jQ (Though I'm assuming this is just basic javascript rather than anything jQuery-related)

EDIT: Also, does the MAILTO: href not work? I tried it and didn't receive an email... anyway, thanks!

Comment: Please rephrase your question to better explain what "this" and "this" are.

Comment: Your colour scheme is impressive :|

Comment: You have not said what exactyl is not working. First check the debugger console for any output errors. You can also use JSLINT button in fiddle to check your code. After that either revert your change and apply it one-by-one, testign in between. Or add `console.log()` to your new code to check selectors, variables and everything else which may break the new code. If you have definet errors re-phrase your question instead of a blanked request "Its not working, can you fix it".

Comment: @NamidaAneskans, surely that's obvious once you follow this links? What would you suggest changing them to?

Comment: @RichardDalton I know xD Just wanted some glaring colors to help make things obvious for me

Comment: @FrançoisWahl Good point, sorry. Shall do this in the future!

Comment: @BertieWheen My suggestion would be to formulate a complete question on SO and use links to provide examples and more in-depth information, rather than to rely on people clicking your links just to find out what the question is.

Comment: @NamidaAneskans I see what you mean, its just I wasn't really sure what was wrong, and as such couldn't provide more in-depth information

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should change these:

```
$("#name").focusout(checkName());
```

to

```
$("#name").focusout(checkName);
```

You want to assign *the function itself* as a `focusout` handler, but instead you're assigning *whatever the function returns* as a handler.

Also, the `mailto:` URL scheme does not send emails. It opens whatever local mail client is defined as handler for this scheme on the visitor's machine and commences composition of a new message addressed to the address in the URL.

Answer (score 2):

Pass the function name, not the result of the function executed.

```
$("#name").focusout(checkName);
$("#pass").focusout(checkPass);
$("#pass2").focusout(checkPass2);
```

Comment: As with lanzz's answer, thank you! :D

Answer (score 2):

Add `var` infront of your function names (not completely necessary but stops them being global):

```
var checkName = function(){
```

And then pass them to the event binding functions without the () as this is running the function and passing the result rather than passing the actual function itself:

```
$("#name").focusout(checkName);
```

This should fix the problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/infernalbadger/Hxnv5/6/

Also, the mailto: link works fine. It should open up your default email client.